# Will Test Automation Framework Gauge be out of Beta this year?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, getgauge

I'm implementing the Gauge framework in the company where I work for. I'd like to know if they are planning to be out of Beta this year and if they do, will new or existing features will still be open source? (use for free or there will be an enterprise version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! 1.0 will be out soon. All the features that you see now will be free and open source.

Comment: It's out of beta now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Gauge v1.0 is released now. If you need to install it, you can easily update via chocolatey command.

```
choco upgrade gauge
```

Or else, you can easily download the archive from [here](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/releases/tag/v1.0.0) and add it to system path.

For more info, please go through [this](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/installation.html) documentation.

And Gauge is totally free and open source software.